# Microsoft Speaker Recognition API - Bad request

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to figure out the Speaker Recognition and found this repo on github that I am using to test it out: https://github.com/rposbo/speaker-recognition-api. However, when I try to enroll a new profile I always get the message:

> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid Http Request"}}

Ugh. I can't poll, it's all gone wrong.

I have checked the https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services to test it and I see that my profiles are being created but the audio is not being saved. I can record and listen to my audio but it seems that is not being saved.
I am wondering what I am missing here to make this work..
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out? If it's not working at all, you may be sending the wrong audio format. The speaker recogntion api is very finicky about receiving 16kHz 16bit wav with a length of at least 1s (there are quite a few [additional requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/identification/textindependent/createenrollment))

Comment: Hi @Ingo. Yes I figured it out after a while and also contacted the person who created that project and he fixed it. The problem was with the format of the audio and I also added some validations to see if the audio was more than a sec and things like that.

Comment: Thank you lumayara, I had figured it out too in the meantime.